# How can I sort numbers in stringlist?

Tags: sorting, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a string list containing some numbers. I have sorted them using a bubble sort that I wrote. The output is:

```
18
20
3
44
53
```

I cannot understand why this above was output rather than what I expected:

```
3
18
20
44
53
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to compare 20 and 3...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783550/), you are sorting the strings as text characters, not as integers.

You can use the [`TStringList.CustomSort()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.CustomSort) method, converting the strings to integers when comparing them:

```
function MySortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value1, Value2: Integer;
begin
  Value1 := StrToInt(List[Index1]);
  Value2 := StrToInt(List[Index2]);
  if Value1 < Value2 then
    Result := -1
  else if Value2 < Value1 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

SL.Add('18');
SL.Add('20');
SL.Add('3');
SL.Add('44');
SL.Add('53');
SL.CustomSort(MySortProc);
```

Alternatively, store the actual integer values in the `Objects` property so you do not have to continuously convert the strings while sorting:

```
function MySortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value1, Value2: Integer;
begin
  Value1 := Integer(List.Objects[Index1]);
  Value2 := Integer(List.Objects[Index2]);
  if Value1 < Value2 then
    Result := -1
  else if Value2 < Value1 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

SL.Add('18', TObject(18));
SL.Add('20', TObject(20));
SL.Add('3', TObject(3));
SL.Add('44', TObject(44));
SL.Add('53', TObject(53));
SL.CustomSort(MySortProc);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`StrCmpLogicalW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947.aspx) to let Windows compare the strings for you:

```
function StrCmpLogicalW(const psz1, psz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'Shlwapi.dll';

function MySortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PChar(List[Index1]), PChar(List[Index2]));
end;

SL.Add('18');
SL.Add('20');
SL.Add('3');
SL.Add('44');
SL.Add('53');
SL.CustomSort(MySortProc);
```

Comment: Suggestion to keep integer value in field of TObject is really bad idea i think, it may lead people to dangerous way. There are TList<integer>/TArray<integer> etc. Custom sort function is also much more elegant solution than conversion between pointer and integer types.

Comment: Suggestion for `MySortProc`: You don't need to check whether `Value1` is smaller or bigger than `Value2`. `SortProc` just needs to return zero, a negative or a positve `integer` to indicate which value is bigger. Replace the `if..else` construct with `Result := Value1 - Value2;`

Comment: @Wosi We had this conversation already. Remy's answer originally did just that. But ask yourself what the output of this program is: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  i, j: Integer;

begin
  i := high(Integer);
  j := low(Integer);
  Writeln(i-j);
end.
`  Does it output a positive value, or a negative value? What do you think? This is an incredibly common anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan I didn't think about that edge case.

Comment: I would `MySortProc` return the result of `StrCmpLogicalW`.

Comment: what is the best approach to sort string like this `AA : 112` ?

Comment: [`StrCmpLogicalW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947.aspx) should be able to handle that.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you don't need to write your own sort code to sort those strings in your string list. The string list class comes with a sort function. You can use that rather than writing your own sort code.

Now moving on to the crux of the question, in the output from your program those values are ordered correctly, when treated as **text**. They are correctly ordered by lexicographic or dictionary order. For instance

```
'20' < '3'
```

because text is compared character by character, and `'2' < '3'`.

But you want the values to be ordered as **numbers**. In which case you should first convert them to numbers, and then sort numbers rather than text. Do that by:

- Create an array `TArray<Integer>`, sized to hold each value of your string list.
- Populate the array  using `StrToInt` to convert each string from the list to an integer.
- Sort the array using [`TArray.Sort<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort) from the `Generics.Collections` unit.

Or perhaps a better approach is not to store the values as text in the first place. Hold the data as an array or list of integers and then sort that. After all, if your data are integer valued it makes sense to store them as such.

If you hold the data in an array, you can sort as described above with `TArray.Sort<T>`. Or if you use `TList<T>` then avail yourself of its [`Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Sort) method.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach quite similar to that of Remy, but instead of using `CustomSort` it uses a new class derived from `TStringList` that overrides `CompareStrings`. The implementation uses `CompareValue` from *System.Math* and the string helper function `ToInteger`.

The advantage is that the new class can have the `Sorted` property set to true (which triggers a sort btw). This makes the `Find` function work, which in turn is used by `IndexOf`. Also newly added (Integer) strings are inserted in sorted order.

```
type
  TIntegerStringList = class(TStringList)
  protected
    function CompareStrings(const S1: string; const S2: string): Integer; override;
  end;

function TIntegerStringList.CompareStrings(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
begin
  result := CompareValue(S1.ToInteger, S2.ToInteger);
end;
```

If this is not a requirement I would also opt for David's solution for performance reasons.

Comment: Just note that you need `System.SysUtils` in your `uses` clause to use the `String.ToInteger()` helper.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `TStringList` (list of string), so the sort works for strings, not numbers.
A simple solution is use the sort method that comes witgh `TStringList`.
You must introduce a small variant in code.

If you are using `TStringList` you are converting Numbers to Strings and viceversa. With the same work you can insert the Numbers in `TStringList` with a format that make the sort method work correctly.

1. Create the `TStringList` (`Sorted` property is False -default-)
2. When you insert the numbers on `TStringList` (and convert it to Strings), use '0' on left part.

> 00000018
>
> 00000020
>
> 00000003
>
> 00000044
>
> 00000053

3. Change the `Sorted` property to `True` and let the `TStringList` make the work.
4. Now the numbers are sorted.

> 00000003
>
> 00000018
>
> 00000020
>
> 00000044
>
> 00000053

5. When you obtain a number convert the string with standard `StrToInt` as you did before.

Comment: @David Heffernen

I thank editing my messages because my English is sometimes not right, but I do not understand the last edition removing a greeting.
According to the rules should edit posts as this:
(1) fix grammatical or spelling errors.  
(2) clarify meaning without changing it.  
(3) correct minor mistakes.  
(4) add related resources or links.  
(5) always respect the original the author.   
Why should eliminate a greeting message? Does this not contradict the point (5)?

Comment: This has been covered on meta many times, for instance http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers  I see now that all your posts seem to be signed off in the same way. You should stop doing that I believe.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Ok David. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is described by David - transform strings into array of integers, sort that array and then re-create the stringlist if you must (or better keep it integerlist).

I would add the most lazy approach though. It might be good enough for small lists (about 100 lines) but it would be slower than the proper method aforementioned, and it would get more and more slow the more items you have.

The lazy approach is to install Jedi Code Library and use the enhanced StringList.

- http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org
- http://github.com/project-jedi/jcl

There you can do it like this:

```
var sl: iJclStringList;

begin
  sl := JclStringList();

  sl.Split( '18, 20, 3, 44, 53', ',' ).Trim().SortAsInteger();

  ShowMessage( sl.Join(', ') );
  ShowMessage( sl.Join(^M^J) );

  sl := nil;
end;
```

Again, this method is doing lot of redundant extra work, so for any more or less significant data amounts proper way of using integers is much preferred.